# .NET multithread async

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'm having trouble getting through my head how I would go about doing this, I've tried looking for examples but I can't really find what I need.

So I've got lets say 20 threads.

Each thread loops and every x amount of loops they should start a changeip batch file on the server.

However I only want this done one time, not repeated by x amount of threads. How would I make this only executed once and not once on every single thread.

Comment: What are these threads doing the other x-1 loops?

Comment: Could you explain further: Why do you need multiple threads, and why do you need loops in these threads, esp. given that some operation should only be executed once?

Answer (score 4):

First, why do you think you need 20 threads?  Most people don't really understand threading and think that more threads means their software will run faster.  That may be the case, but may not be.  In particular, you only have 1-n cores, which is most likely not 20 cores.. so you can only execute at max, however many cores you have simultaneously.

However, to answer your actual question, this has little to do with threading per se, but threading does complicate it.

You have several problems here.  The first is, each thread runs in its own time slice, and you will get one thread that executes 10 loops in one slice, another thread might only execute 5.. given any particular block of time, your loops will gradually become unsynchronized in how many times they've executed.  This might not be an actual problem, but if it is, you will need to find a way to synchronize the threads, such as by waiting for all loops to finish before moving to the next set of loops.

So the next question is.. when you say every x loops (let's say 20), which threads loops?  the first one that does 20?  When all have done 20?  Or do you mean 20 loops across all threads (ie, each has executed once?)

Perhaps the easiest way is to have a static variable, which you control via an InterlockedIncrement method to prevent multiple threads from trying to access it at the same time.  Each thread increments the number, and when it reaches 20, one of those threads (the one that's incrementing at that moment) executes your batch file.

Comment: So basically, 20 threads are sending web requests right, (each thread is looping) after 100 loops I want to run a batch that changes the computers ip address. However my problem is that if all threads think they need to change their ip then they try to do it at the same time, when it only needs to be done once.

Comment: @user2579668 - sounds like you're doing something fishy to me (trying to bypass restrictions).  But in any event, you're going to run into many problems.  For instance, if you change the IP address while other threads are downloading, their downloads will abort.  You have to wait for all threads to finish before you can do so.  In this case, i'd suggest having a "traffic cop" thread that parcels out download requests, and waits for them to finish, once your 100 downloads complete, your traffic cop changes the ip, then issues another 100 requests.  I'd use a Queue.

Comment: Also realize that anyone connected to the computer (other than the person at the console) will be disconnected as well.

Comment: Yes I realize, that is not my issue

Comment: I guess I could have an entire seperate thread that loops through a variable and when it's beyond a point then we change our ip

Comment: @user2579668 - but like I said, you have to wait for all current downloads to complete before doing so, or your downloads will abort.  So you have to let them complete and not start any new ones until after the ip has been changed.